# Powershell RDP authentication on domain

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, remote-access, rdp

I'm trying to create a powershell script to start and authenticate an RDP session to multiple machines by IP range.

I'm very new to powershell, and windows/domain scripting in general.

I have written a powershell script using Connect-Mstsc that allows me to enter my username and password, as well as an IP range and it works, opens a session to all machines in the range and uses the credentials to authenticate me to connect to the machines.

My issue is, I'd like this script to perform *LOCAL* authentication on the machines as well, right now, when it runs, if I give it a range of say, 5 IP addresses, it opens 5 RDP sessions to the machines, which is good, but each session is sitting there at the login prompt. I would like it to automatically log me in on each machine locally using the same user/password I supply, and then hopefully execute a batch file from a network share on login.

I've done quite a bit of research on this, and I've come up empty, and given my beginner experience level I'm not sure I'm even looking in the right places.

Comment: Please include what you have so far, it will help others answer your question.

Comment: Also what are you trying to RDP to, what server\OS?

Comment: I don't have it with me right now unfortunately, but it's literally just this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-Mstsc-Open-RDP-2064b10b and a for loop to loop the last octet of a supplied ip range. Destination machines are Windows 7.

Comment: I'd recommend using an existing [RDP Connection Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989) rather than trying to re-invent the wheel. If you're trying to remotely execute commands *without* user interaction: drop RDP altogether and use [PowerShell Remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx) instead.

Comment: RDP Connection manager looks promising, I didn't know such a thing existed. :D  Powershell remoting isn't an option sadly, because some of the actions I'm going to perform will require periodic user interaction.